# Check if android phone is rooted from PC

Tags: android, rooted-device

I am trying to find a fast way to see if an android phone is rooted or not. I know you can use root checker app but due to numbers of phones it is far too slow to install and use.

I am looking for a way that I use. I know I have to turn ADB on, on the phone and plug it into my pc.

Is there a way to check this using command a line I can run in CMD?

I have android studio install so is there a way of running a script from this that will check to see if a phone has been rooted?

I know what due to number of way a phone can be rooted it not always 100% but I can live with that.

Comment: i think this question is better to be asked here http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about phone-rooting and flashing, not programming.

Answer (score -1):

I know two ways you can check if you android is rooted.

1. Installing an "Root Checker" app from the Play Store.
2. Installing a Rooting software that check the android when is conected, try Kingo Root.